# Is there a function in Prelude to pair a value with that value applied to a function?

Tags: haskell, haskell-prelude

I am searching for a function which looks something similar to this:

`withSelf :: (a -> b) -> a -> (a, b)
withSelf f x = (x, f x)`

I have searched with Hoogle for such a function; I searched for [`(a -> b) -> a -> (a, b)`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+b%29++-%3E+a+-%3E+%28a%2C+b%29) and [`a -> (a -> b) -> (a, b)`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=a+-%3E+%28a+-%3E+b%29++-%3E+%28a%2C+b%29), neither of which were conclusive. The [Hackage page on `Data.Tuple`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Tuple.html) doesn't have what I'm looking for either.

I'm aware that it's trivial to write, but I want to write idiomatic Haskell where possible, and avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: Hayoo will find some: http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+a+-%3E+%28a%2Cb%29 but I doubt that those are more idiomatic (if you have to fetch those libs just for this) than redefining it quick and easy

Comment: One of the nice things about very polymorphic functions like this in a language like Haskell is that there's basically only one way to define a function with type `(a -> b) -> a -> (a, b)`. So in a sense you don't have to worry about reinventing wheels like this; the type system *forces* your wheel to be just as good as anyone else's! ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The section `(id &&&)` does what you want:

```
> import Control.Arrow
> :t (id &&&)
(id &&&) :: (a -> c') -> a -> (a, c')
> (id &&&) succ 4
(4,5)
```

Comment: I knew when I read the question that the answer would be in `Control.Arrow`, but I can never, ever remember what the different functions in there do.

Comment: I like this answer - although I hope I will never see something like this in *real* code ;) (to the uninitiated (noob) *eye* (like mine) `\f a -> (a, f a)` is just easier to read)

Comment: @dfeuer well I guess you are right - the big question is: is this a good thing? - but I guess this is not the right place for such discussions and you already got my upvote too - so have a nice day

Comment: @CarstenKönig Indeed, I think I'm more likely to use the plain version in real code. The step from point-free to point-less can be very short.

Comment: Thanks, I'm relatively new to Haskell and its control structures, so I'll take a look at `Control.Arrow` now.

Comment: @Quackmatic If you are new, keep in mind that arrows are quite abstract. You may want to look at functors and/or monads first.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to use `Control.Arrow`, you can always use `Applicative`:

```
withSelf f = (,) <$> id <*> f
```

Many people will probably actually understand this immediately, but for something so simple it's pretty silly.

#### Edit

As pointed out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29332229/is-there-a-function-in-prelude-to-pair-a-value-with-that-value-applied-to-a-func/29332580?noredirect=1#comment46864518_29332580), this can be written even more briefly as

```
withSelf = ((,) <*>)
```

This astonished me at first, but it's actually very simple: for `(->) r`, `fmap = (.)`, so the `<$> id` is completely redundant!

Comment: Compared to the obvious definition this is ridiculously complex. :)

Comment: It's simply `withSelf = ((,) <*>)`

Comment: `ap (,)` is shorter :)